# Which design pattern should be used to avoid other implementations?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am trying to create a simple game that can work in different platforms as a proof of concept. For now I am happy to have it working for both J2SE (using AWT or Swing) and Android. I decided to use Java for the logic of the game as both platforms expects Java code. The idea is creating a set of interfaces to abstract the OS and have a clean straight-forward game logic using these interfaces. And having 2 implementations of these interfaces, one per platform.

Some code to describe what I mean:

```
public class MyGameLogic implements GameLogic {  

    private GameSprite _sprite;

    @Override
    public void init(GamePlatform platform) {  
        _sprite = platform.loadSprite("arena");
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(GameCanvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawSprite(_sprite, 100, 200);
    }
}
```

Here GamePlatform, GameSprite and GameCanvas would be interfaces. These interfaces will be implemented in a different way for the different platforms depending on the platform capabilities and APIs. In a similar way, GameLogic is an interface that is implemented by the game logic and not the platform. The platform will use the GameLogic interface to initialise the logic and redrawing every time is required, but more method are expected to be added in the future.

Even if I think this option is great, I see 2 flows in this design:
 * the game logic can create its own implementation of GameSprite and call drawSprite() with it, which is not expected by the platform implementation.
 * the implementation of the platforms must cast back all the interfaces in order they can access the real data inside the GameSprite. So if the GameSprite returned in loadSprite for J2SE is in reality a J2SESprite class, which implements GameSprite, when calling draw() I should cast the GameSprite back to J2SESprite.

In order to solve the problem I thought in adding generics, but it will make the code really ugly, here is the same code with generics.

```
public class MyGameLogic<
        Sprite extends GameSprite,
        Platform extends GamePlatform,
        Canvas extends GameCanvas>
    implements GameLogic<Platform, Canvas> {  

    private Sprite _sprite;

    @Override
    public void init(Platform platform) {  
        _sprite = platform.loadSprite("arena");
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawSprite(_sprite, 100, 200);
    }
}
```

This way, the game logic will not be able to call new Sprite(), as it is a generic type nor extending it, which solves the first problem, and we do not need to cast it back as the generics will provide the proper type. The problem is that I have to add the generics in all my game logic classes, and there is a generic parameter for each interface, and can be a lot at the end.

Is there any better solution? Any design pattern I am not aware of that I can use for this purpose?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you saying that you have to cast to a concrete sprite implementation? From GameSprite to J2SESprite.

Comment: @bigdestroyer The implementation of GameSprite may be different for each platform. For example, it can be a class containing a byte array for the pixel data or it can be instead a reference to a resource that has been previously load in the GPU memory. The game logic should not know what is behind the GameSprite, however the platform/canvas needs to know it. So a cast to the real implementation is required before manipulating the sprite data. J2SESprite is the name I gave to the J2SE implementation, but the name itself is irrelevant.

Comment: I understand. You can make a design where the concrete clases know how it has to be drawed. Inversion of control. You should to find a design where casting is not required.

Answer (score 0):

You have one game that might have two or more user interfaces ( Swing, Android). For business applications it is common to separate the user interface from the *business logic*. The business logic is placed in a *service layer*, which is an internal API used just by the user interface code. The service layer manipulates and provides *domain objects* that represent what the program is about. The user interface code is placed in a separate *presentation layer*. It translates user inputs into calls to the service layer and translates domain objects returned from theservice layer into user interface changes.

You could use a similar design. You would have different implementations of the presentation layer (for Swing and Android) but the same service layer.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I think this is exactly what I am trying to achieve. In this case GameSprite, GamePlatform and GameCanvas are implemented by the presentation layer, and MyGameLogic is actually my business logic. But what I am asking for any design pattern that can keep this architecture with a clean code and how to avoid that the business logic can create implementations for interfaces that only the presentation layer should provide. Any ideas?